# How to setState for react useState hook, array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Here,  using an array I have mapped the input boxes, and the value which has entered in that array should be stored in an usestate hook and on click of submit button it should console the array of objects. How to acheive this? Thank You.

```
const AddCheckPoint = ({ master }) => {
    const [addChecklist, setAddChecklist] = useState([])
    const [addChecklistValues, setAddChecklistValues] = useState({})
    const submit = () => {
        setShow(false)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(addChecklist))
    }
    const getFormDetails = (val, id) => {
        setAddChecklistValues(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            ch_id: id,
            value: val
        }));
        setAddChecklist(prevArray => [...prevArray, addChecklistValues])
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Row><Col><b>SLno</b></Col><Col><b>Checkpoint</b></Col><Col><b>Value</b></Col></Row>
            {master && master.map((r, i) => {
                return (<Form.Group key={i} className="mb-3" controlId={i}>
                    <Row><Col><Form.Label>{r.slno}</Form.Label></Col><Col><Form.Label>{r.checkPoint}</Form.Label></Col><Col><Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" onChange={e => getFormDetails(e.target.value, r._id)} /></Col></Row>
                </Form.Group>)
            })}
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={submit}>Submit</Button>
        </>
    );
}
export default AddCheckPoint
```

> And the prop "master" looks like the follows

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61028558b45073399077becd",
    "slno": "A1",
    "checkPoint": "Position of adaptor CAT",
    "cellName": "PC - 1",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-29T10:39:20.902Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-29T10:39:20.902Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "61028567b45073399077becf",
    "slno": "A2",
    "checkPoint": "Flush height of Adaptor CAT position",
    "cellName": "PC - 1",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-29T10:39:35.752Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-29T10:39:35.752Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add simple by create a new value and pass it into `setAddChecklistValues` and `setAddChecklist`

```
const getFormDetails = (val, id) => {
  const newValue = {
    ch_id: id,
    value: val,
  };
  setAddChecklistValues(newValue);
  setAddChecklist((prevArray) => [...prevArray, newValue]);
};
```

Comment: since it is onChange of input, on console i'll get something like this.   [{"ch_id":"61028558b45073399077becd","value":"aa"},{"ch_id":"61028567b45073399077becf","value":"h"},{"ch_id":"61028567b45073399077becf","value":"hh"},{"ch_id":"61028572b45073399077bed1","value":"h"},{"ch_id":"61028572b45073399077bed1","value":"hh"},{"ch_id":"61028572b45073399077bed1","value":"hhh"}]

Comment: Yeah i've only given values for 2 input fields

Comment: what data do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here as you are using onchange u must use debouncing technique to get correct the array of the objects. Refer Following url:
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/debouncing-and-throttling-in-javascript or you can replace below function in your code :

const getFormDetails = (val, id) => {
setAddChecklistValues((prevState) => ({
...prevState,
ch_id: id,
value: val
}));
setAddChecklist((prevArray) => {
const k = prevArray.filter((e) => {
return e.ch_id === addChecklistValues.ch_id;
});
if (k.length > 0) {
prevArray.map((e) => {
if (e.ch_id === addChecklistValues.ch_id) {
e.value = addChecklistValues.value;
}
return e;
});
return prevArray;
}
return [...prevArray, addChecklistValues];
});
};